# В чём разница алгоритма Wu и алгоритма Gupta-Sproull

Tags: графика

В чём состоит их разница? Казалось бы, оба алгоритма для рисования сглаженных прямых. Есть ли вообще какое-либо внятное их сравнение по качеству\производительности?

Comment: вот здесь уделывают Wu http://akme-a2.iosb.fraunhofer.de/EatThisGoogleScholar/d/2010_Fast,%20high-quality%20line%20antialiasing%20by%20prefiltering%20with%20an%20optimal%20cubic%20polynomial.pdf но вы явно недостаточно гуглили, кстати

Comment: @strangeqargo Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.